# How to create data model for PrimeNG TreeTable for angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng

I am trying to use the PrimeNG treetable in angular 5. As per documentation it needs data in particular format. Is there a recommended way to convert custom data in required format ? Right now I am getting json array through http get service in following format, where relatedkey specify the children of the data. so need to iterate json array to get the children with keys mentioned in relatedKey array. Or should it be server who should send data in required format ?

**input json**
     --- EDITED : NOT THE EXCAT DATA BUT SOMETHING LIKE BELOW----

```
[
    {key:key1, name: "A", features:{"f1":"CFB","f2":"CDB"}, relatedkey:[key2,key4}], Parent :true },
    {key:key2,name:"B", features:{"f1":"dsn","f2":"dsdfd"},relatedkey:[key3], Parent :false },
    {key:key3, name: "C", features:{"f1":"nn","f2":"bbb"},relatedkey:[], Parent :false},
     {key:key4,name: "D",features:{"f1":"Cn","f2":"nn"}, relatedkey:[], Parent :false}
 ]
```

**expected json**

```
     {
 "data":
 [  
    {  
        "data":{  
            "name":"Documents",
            "size":"75kb",
            "type":"Folder"
        },
        "children":[
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"Work",
                    "size":"55kb",
                    "type":"Folder"
                },
                "children":[  
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"Expenses.doc",
                            "size":"30kb",
                            "type":"Document"
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"Resume.doc",
                            "size":"25kb",
                            "type":"Resume"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"Home",
                    "size":"20kb",
                    "type":"Folder"
                },
                "children":[  
                    {  
                        "data":{  
                            "name":"Invoices",
                            "size":"20kb",
                            "type":"Text"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "data":{  
            "name":"Pictures",
            "size":"150kb",
            "type":"Folder"
        },
        "children":[  
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"barcelona.jpg",
                    "size":"90kb",
                    "type":"Picture"
                }
            },
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"primeui.png",
                    "size":"30kb",
                    "type":"Picture"
                }
            },
            {  
                "data":{  
                    "name":"optimus.jpg",
                    "size":"30kb",
                    "type":"Picture"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You have to transform your data manually, from the server or in your TS code. Can you explicit what contains `data1` for instance please ?

Comment: added sample data. it is basically array with some name value pair  specifying key, name , features etc etc,

Answer (score 0):

While working with TreeTable I used to have the following sent from my server side.

```
public class SummaryObj {
 private boolean leaf;
 private boolean expanded;
 private TreeNodeData data;
 private List<SummaryObj> children;
}
public class TreeNodeData {
  private String name;
}
```

Here SummaryObj would auto-map to your type required on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of transforming your data manually, you just need to customize treenode.d.ts file as per your requirement like I did the following way

```
export interface TreeNode {
label?: string;
data?: any;
icon?: any;
expandedIcon?: any;
collapsedIcon?: any;
children?: TreeNode[];
leaf?: boolean;
expanded?: boolean;
type?: string;
parent?: TreeNode;
partialSelected?: boolean;
styleClass?: string;
draggable?: boolean;
droppable?: boolean;
selectable?: boolean;
level?: any;
ParentOrganizationHierarchyGUID?:any;}
```

I want one extra property so added ParentOrganizationHierarchyGUID field in treenode.d.ts file
**path: node_modules\primeng\components\common**

Comment: I tired to change the Treenode Model but there is no content in the UI. @pArth savadiya

Comment: OMG This answer ... Parth, i hope you came here and realize now this is so wrong